# How to call a variable from a string with the same name? PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a number of arrays like so:

```
$fruitArray = array(
 "orange" => "orange",
 "banana" => "yellow",
 "apple" => "green"
);

$carsArray = array(
 "ford" => array (
   "truck" => "big",
   "car" => "small"
 ),
 "mazda" => "yellow",
 "toyota" => "green"
);
```

Normally I could just use var_dump($carsArray[ford]) but I don't know which parts I need.
But I can get the names from other variables. For example,

```
$firstWordInArrayName = cars;
$carType = ford;
```

I want to create a variable that allows me to access the a specific array like so:

```
$variableToCallArrayName = '$' . $firstWordInArrayName . 'Array[' . $cartype . ']';
var_dump($variableToCallArrayName)
```

Is this a good way of doing this or is there some other way of doing this?
And if it is okay, how do I do it please?

Comment: I think it would be easier to organize the data instead. Like having one array containing the other arrays: `$stuff = ['cars' => '[...], 'fruits' => [....]]` and so on. Then it would be clearer with just `$stuff[$theType]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a [variable variables syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$variableToCallArrayName = ${$firstWordInArrayName . 'Array'}[$cartype];

var_dump($variableToCallArrayName);
```